# Best algorithm to find a key within a range from hashtable

Tags: json, hashmap, hashtable

**Problem**

From below list of items I will need to access the item by identifying key range with given value for instance lets say if the value is 2.1.1 which is in degree, minutes & seconds I need to find key 0.0.0-30.0.0
performance is high priority.

```
key: 0.0.0-30.0.0   value: x-y-z
key: 30.0.0-60.0.0  value: y-x-z
key: 60.0.0-90.0.0  value: z-y-z
```

**Solution1:**
Below solutions I have attempted so far

recreate new key/value (json) file as below

```
key: 0.0.0  value: x-y-z
key: 0.0.1  value: x-y-z
.
key: 0.0.59 value: x-y-z
.
key: 0.1.0 value x-y-z
key: 0.1.1 value x-y-z

key: 30.0.0  value: y-x-z
.
.
key: 30.0.59 value: y-x-z
.
key: 30.1.0 value: y-x-z
key: 30.1.1 value: y-x-z
key: 30.1.2 value: y-x-z
.
.
key: 30.1.59 value: y-x-z
key: 30.2.0 value: y-x-z
key: 30.2.1 value: y-x-z
key: 30-2.3 value: y-x-z
.
.
key: 60.0.0 value: z-y-x
key: 60.0.1 value: z-y-x
key: 60.0.2 value: z-y-x
.
.
key: 60.0.59 value: z-y-x
key: 60.1.0 value: z-y-x
key: 60.1.1 value: z-y-x
.
.
```

**Issue(s)**
The issue with above solution is the file size will be increased  which is causing heap overflow in my compact app

**Solution2**

?

Comment: Do the ranges overlap? Are there unmapped ranges? My first thought is to put them into a sorted array, then binary search in there.

Comment: your question is not clear enough. so, what you are trying to do is to get a set/list of key/values pairs  based on a range of keys in your example from 0.0.0 to 30.0.0, correct?

Comment: Json file contains key in the format degfrom.minfrom.secfrom-degto.minto.secto and the input will be something like deg1.min1.sec1 what I want is to quickly able find a key range in which deg1.min1.sec1 falls into

Comment: The key range is in sorted array binary search maybe expensive as these are not direct numbers hence parsing converting from DMS to decimal and then performing comparison could have a performance issue, this function to be triggered every second

Comment: is it ok to load json file conent in memory. how big is the json file?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A hash table is poorly suited to this problem, as hash tables work best when all the keys you may look up are stored in the table: you've said you don't have the memory for that.  A binary search is indeed a good way to do this, but you mention...

> The key range is in sorted array binary search maybe expensive as these are not direct numbers hence parsing converting from DMS to decimal and then performing comparison could have a performance issue, this function to be triggered every second.

Firstly, a C++ program can do a *lot* of work in a tiny fraction of one second - even an unoptimised lookup is likely to work plenty fast enough, but let's assume for a moment that you did need closer to optimal speed...

"parsing from DMS" is vague, but I'm assuming you mean you have a textual representation of a key such as "2.1.1" coming into your program: it's almost certainly better to parse this than having to do a lookup using text comparisons.  To parse text in a "C++ style", you can simply use...

```
std::istringstream iss(the_incoming_key);
int degree, minute, second;
char c1, c2;
if (iss >> degree >> c1 >> minute >> c2 >> seconds &&
    c1 == '.' && c2 == '.')
{
    // have parsed a valid key...
}
else
    error_throw_exit_whatever();
```

If you were prepared to use an older C function for extra speed, consider:

```
if (sscanf(the_incoming_key.c_str(), "%d.%d.%d", &degree, &minute, &second) == 3)
    // have parsed a valid key...
```

Having parsed the key, you could reasonably:

1) have `std::map<tuple<int8_t, int8_t, int8_t>, Value> values;` and binary search with `std::make_tuple(degree, minute, second)`, or

2) have `std::map<int, Value> values;` and binary search with `degree * 3600 + minute * 60 + second` - a *total number of seconds* value that might or might not be faster for your computer to compare.

a. Multiplication is a bit slow though, so `(degree << 12) + (minute << 6) + second` could be used to avoid it, given six bits is more than enough to store values between 0 and 59.

Of course whatever transformation you do to create the key needs to have been used earlier when parsing the json file and populating the table.

For even more optimisation, you could have an array of 360 maps, and index into the specific map you want to find the minutes and seconds components.  Dividing the search space by 360 can be expected to eliminate 8 or 9 comparisons as you do each map lookup (as each comparison halves the number of elements still in contention, and 360 is between 2^8 and 2^9).

Comment: I wanted javascript solution thru' your solution looks perfect for server sided but in my case hitting the server every second may also too expensive, hope this code can be ported to javascript let me give a try, thanks anyways

Comment: @Naga: oh sorry - I usually focus on C++ questions and when I was checking the hashtable tag forgot to check which language you were using.  Bit of googling suggests regular expressions are commonly used for parsing in Javascript - something like `dms_string.match(/\\d+\\.?\\*/g)` should return an array of substrings you can call `Number` on to extract the integral values?  I'm a bit lost as to what your client/server situation is: if your search keys are coming in client side, then you either need the data structure to search there,  or to ping the server - can't see how that can be avoided.

Answer (score 0):

Since your entries in the first json are sorted in order, you can parse your input and use it to calculate the position and generate the key of the entry.

With the first list I would parse the input value as 3 ints. For this one we only need the first part of the input (degree).
And then we get the position like this:

```
 int position = input_degree / step_size;
```

step_size would be 30 with your first list.

If you need the key you can generate it now using the position:

```
String key_begin = position * step_size;
String search_key = key_begin + ".0.0-" + key_begin+step_size + ".0.0";
```

Answer (score 0):

Use KD-tree or R-tree data structures instead of hash maps.